# C# console.title in php?

Tags: php

is there anything similar to c# console.title in php ?

What I want to do exactly is to change the console title while running the php script

So for example each time a loop is done the console title changes to the current loop number, I'm currently just using `echo $i . "\n";` where $i equals to `for ($i = 0; $i <= 4999; $i+=1) { //code here }`but that just prints out each number of loops made. What I want to do is for that to display in the console title or it prints out the number once in the console and changes each loop instead of priting it out every number.

Just an example on how it should look:

```
user$ php test1.php

0
```

After loop is done

```
user$ php test1.php

1
```

or in the console title: cmd- done 0 loops

after loop

cmd- done 1 loop

And so on until is finishes

I tried searching here and on google but there is nothing that I could find.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in to the language that I'm aware of, but you can use

```php
exec("title done $i loops");
```

This will call the `title` command line utility, which only works on Windows. It will also only work while your program is running. As soon as it finishes, the title will go back to whatever it was before your program was called.

Comment: Thank you so much !, that kinda what I was looking for : ) Wish it worked on putty as well either way thanks !